# Should I create a class instance from inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class that optionally takes a serial port as an argument. I want to create an enumerate function that will return an array of MyClass objects all with unique ports. I'm very unsure about where this enumerate function should live though. It feels somewhat nicer wrapped up if I put it inside the class like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, port=None):
        self.port = port

    def enumerate(self):
        ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
        a = []
        for p in ports:
            a.append(MyClass(port))
        return a
```

But I'm very unsure if its good practice to be recursively creating class instances like this. Would it be better practice to pull the enumerate function out and have it exist independent of the class?

Comment: This is exactly what `@classmethod` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jasonharper states in the comments, you can decorate the method with `@classmethod`

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port

    @classmethod
    def enumerate(cls):
        return (cls(p) for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
```

You would call it like this:

```
my_classes = MyClass.enumerate()
```

Comment: Replace reference(s) to `MyClass` in the `classmethod` with `cls`; that's the whole point of class methods (usable in subclasses without modification if subclass construction takes the same arguments).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not super familiar with classmethod, after doing a bit of googling I still don't understand exactly how this is functionally different than calling it without the decorator. What is the difference between `cls` and `self`?

Comment: @Indigo: it is simple: `cls` is `MyClass` itself, `self` -- `MyClass` instance like `MyClass(1337)`

Comment: your code returns `iterator` when there is a `list` in original snippet

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Considering the method is called `enumerate`, I think returning a generator is more appropriate

Comment: it'll be better to leave original behavior unchanged or at least add comment why you think returning `iterator` instead of a `list` is a better idea (also name `my_classes` is misleading, it should be `my_instances` or something like that)